# Fatal error: Class 'Dingo\Api\Auth\Provider\LaravelServiceProvider' not found

Tags: laravel-5, dingo-api

I create new laravel(5.3) project with composer and install dingo package with this command:

`composer require dingo/api:1.0.x@dev`

Then I try to publish it as I see in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r40yAZAi6PQ). Here is the screenshot of my cmd window: 
[image]
I also added `Dingo\Api\Auth\Provider\LaravelServiceProvider::class,` line to my app.php so I couldnt figure out what problem is here.

**EDITED**

I search for file name "LaravelServiceProvider" and find it in "MyProject\vendor\dingo\api\src\Provider\LaravelServiceProvider.php" here.
So the issue I have is path I think.. still working handle it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I just undo and remake same steps but the thing is I didnt update composer after edit composer.json with "composer require dingo/api:1.0.x@dev"
line. I type and enter "composer update". And added class providers and its worked.

Answer (score 0):

open the terminal run this command

```
  composer require dingo/api:1.0.x@dev
```

Answer (score -1):

go to [this api](https://github.com/dingo/api)  and Copy `config/api.php` to your project config folder.

Run `php artisan config:cache` if you have cached configs

Then

`composer require dingo/api`

after that

`php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Dingo\Api\Provider\LaravelServiceProvider"`